# Regex for an html text code in Java

Tags: java, regex

I have a html text file that has headings I would like to extract the only the text inside

Example:

```
<h1 class="title"><a href="dtb.htm#rgn_txt_0001_0001">Fire Safety</a></h1>
<h1><a href="dtb.htm#rgn_txt_0002_0001">About this book</a></h1>
<h1><a href="dtb.htm#rgn_par_0002_0008">1</a></h1>
<h1><a href="dtb.htm#rgn_txt_0003_0001">Contents of this book</a></h1>
```

I would like extract only the following text from HTML code:

**Fire Safety,
About this book,
1,
Contents of this book**

I tried lot of things like:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("<a[^>]href\\s=\\s*\"\\s*([^\"]*)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
```

where **input** is the html data.

Didn't get any results on the console or sometimes are i am getting only href :(

How do I get to fix this?

Let me know!
Thanks!

Comment: Please Please Please! Don't parse HTML with Regex. Try http://jsoup.org/

Comment: You cannot parse HTML with Regex, lest this happens again: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/504685

Comment: @RohitJain It's not that you shouldn't parse HTML with RegEx, it's that you can't.

Comment: K. why can't I use regEX. What is issue behind it? More over it is not HTML file but it is just HTML source code that are on a text?

Comment: @user1443051  HTML is a non-regular context free language. You can only describe regular languages with regular expressions though. See any introductory article on formal languages for details.

Answer (score 3):

I would strongly recommend to use an HTML parser, something like [TagSoup](http://home.ccil.org/~cowan/XML/tagsoup/), [Jericho](http://jericho.htmlparser.net/docs/index.html), [NekoHTML](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nekohtml/), [HTML Parser](http://htmlparser.sourceforge.net/), etc

Comment: I don't have any information on the parser that are available.

Comment: @user1443051 ... and that's why NullPointer gave you links to 4 of them.